# SSRS 2012 - 401 unauthorized error when running from a web page using a service account credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a requirement where an aspx page needs to generate and display a report  in browser when the necessary input values are passed. The web page uses the ReportViewer control to invoke the .rdl file which is available in remote server WIN12ABC to generate and display the report. Below code is used for this purpose

```
    rptViewer.ShowCredentialPrompts = false;

            rptViewer.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;

            rptViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = new ReportCredentials("spsqlrptadmin", "AbcD123", "US");

            rptViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://WIN12ABC/ReportServer_ABCD1dev");

            rptViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/SSRSDemo/SSRSDemo";

            List<ReportParameter> parameters = new List<ReportParameter>();

            parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("ID_Number", "86745"));

           rptViewer.ShowParameterPrompts = false;

            rptViewer.ShowPromptAreaButton = false;

            rptViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(parameters);

            rptViewer.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

I am using a service account "spsqlrptadmin" and its credentials to connect to the report server.It has system administator role in Report Manager. If I run the page, I am getting the below error

> 401 unauthorized error.

But if I use another account "rvjeevirptuser" instead of the above one, report is successfully generated and displayed in the browser. This account "rvjeevirptuser" is my personal account which is used specifically for connecting to the remote server WIN12ABC.

I just copied the URL in browser "http://WIN12ABC/ReportServer_ABCD1dev" using the service account "spsqlrptadmin" and navigated to the folder where the report (.rdl) "SSRSDemo" is deployed. I am able to view the report.

I am unable to identify what is causing this "Unauthorized" error while using the account "spsqlrptadmin" alone. I have checked the dbo.users table in ReportServer database to confirm the level of permission given to both users.

I could not find any difference except the  UserType. Further information from ReportServer.dbo.users table is available in the attached image[image]

Comment: Are you seeing a folder structure or a list with link buttons when you browse to the address? http://WIN12ABC/ReportServer_ABCD1dev

Comment: When I browse the above address, I am seeing the list of links for the reports deployed since it is web service URL. I have tried with Report manager URL http://WIN12ABC/Reports_ABCD1dev also. But the results are same (getting 401 - Unauthorized error while using service account "spsqlrptadmin").